# Persist data between two pages with Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-state-management

I would like to refactor my Next.js webapp to have different pages handle different screens. Currently, I have this component holding several states to know in which screen I'm in. In the jsx section, I'm using `{value && ... }` to render the right component.

But I feel this is not good design, and won't be maintainable when adding more and more screens.

I would also like to avoid Redux as it is overkill for my project.

I was thinking about persisting data in cookies so I can retrieve them with getInitialProps in every component when rendering a new page, but is there a more elegant way?

I've read about tweaking the `_app.js` but I'm not sure to understand the consequences of doing so, and how it could help me..

Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you using an express server or serverless functions with next.js.
Do you have any webpages you want to protect?
Is the data you want coming from a database that has anything to do with user authentication.

Comment: Have you thought of using the Context API and hooks?

Comment: react-router ??

Comment: @UzairAshraf backend in golang with graphql on top of mysql. yes I want to protect some pages (although the one I'm concerned with in my question are not). current data not related to the user auth.

Comment: @AjayYadav Are you suggesting to use useContext() to manage the view selection, or to persist data from one page to another?

Comment: @xadm In the context of Next.js, I'm not use how react-router could help me. But maybe you can elaborate so I fully understand your proposition?

Comment: @Binajmen yes you can use useContext() to persist data on different levels. I find it useful for smaller applications instead of Redux

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When multiple of your pages need to make use of same data, you can make use of Context to store the result. It a good way to make a centralized storage without using complex and more self sufficient libraries like `redux`

You can implement context inside of _app.js file which must reside inside your root folder. This way next.js treats it as a root wrapper and you would just need to use 1 instance of Context

contexts/appContext

```
import React from 'react';
const AppContext = React.createContext();
export const AppProvider = AppContext.Provider;
export const AppConsumer = AppContext.Consumer;
export default AppContext;
```

_app.js

```
import React from 'react'
import App from 'next/app'
import AppProvider from '../contexts/appContext';
class MyApp extends App {
  state={
    data:[]
  }
  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;
    // You can implement logic in this component to fetch data and update state
    return (
      <div>
        <AppProvider value={this.state.data}> // pass on value to context
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </AppProvider>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default MyApp
```

Now further each component can make use of context value by using AppConsumer or using `useContext` if you use hooks

Please read more about how to use [Context here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextconsumer)

Comment: How can i use multi page form data with context api in nextjs?

Comment: When using `redux`, we require to use `redux-persist` etc to maintain the state across reloads wtih NextJs but how it works seamless with ContextAPI?

Comment: I have campaign data in http query. I want to use that data throughout the application. I am using getServerSideProps to get the data in component. I  used react context. but the context vanished while surfing to other pages of website. Is there server side session in next js?